# Structure (struct) in Xcode as Array, and global

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to create a structure, which should be used as an array.

Then at the same time I need to access it from a different view, so I'm guessing I need to make it global for now, until I learn a better way (have tried many suggestions from google searches)

But how do I declare a variable twice?

I mean both as my structure, and as an array?

Comment: If you want to use it in another view, pass it to that view by a parameter. Don't make it global

Comment: I agree with @MrAzulay, avoid global variables at all costs.

Comment: You need to add some more detail about what you're trying to do. To make a custom data container, make your own class. If you tell us what scenario you're dealing with that requires multiple views to access a variable someone should be able to help you.

Comment: Then this might be noob question, but how do i pass a variable to another view?

Comment: Are you using storyboards and iOS 5? If so, look into segues. Also, if you need an array, I would use an NSArray, not create a c struct.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "global variables" can be appropriate, but not simply as "global variables".  The proper way to do it in Objective C is with singletons.

Here is part of the .h implementation below:

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;

+ (MySingleton *)sharedSingleton

@end
```

And here is what the .m implementation would look like:

```
@implementation MySingletion
@synthesize myArray;

static MySingleton *shared = nil;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (MySingleton *)sharedSingleton
{
    if(shared == nil)
    {
        shared = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    }

    return shared;
}
```

Then, whenever you wanted to access this from a given class, you would #import "MySingleton.h" and access your array like so:

```
[MySingleton sharedSingleton].myArray
```

Edit:  However, this does not mean that every time you need to pass data it should be done with a singleton.  Singletons are correct in certain situations, but as others have mentioned, you should pass the data to the next class yourself in most situations.

Comment: So a singleton method would be the best way to do a structure like array?

Comment: Well... it would probably be overkill for JUST an array.  But it really depends on the situation.  Could you provide anymore details about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well i just created a new h and m fil, where i put a lot of varibales

using extend in the.h file
and alloc init in the .m file

Then i just include this file where i need the variables. Probably there is a much better way, but this was the only one i could figure out.